# what will happen when I use equals method to compare a string object and stringbuffer object?

Tags: java, string, equals, palindrome, stringbuffer

What will happen when we compare String and Stringbuffer with the method equals?

```java
String s1= "121";
System.out.println();

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s1);
sb.reverse();
System.out.println(sb);

if(s1.equals(sb))
{
    System.out.println("Palindrome");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not palindrome");
}
```

I took a String and store it into `StringBuffer` and I use reverse method to reverse the string. But when I use `equals` method between `String` and `StringBuffer`. It gave me an unexpected result. It returns "Not palindrome".

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Turn the `StringBuffer` into a `String`

Comment: the two aren't of the same type, of course it 'll return false. You'll need to get the String value of the contents of the Buffer, and compare that to your String

Answer (score 2):

The "equals" method of a String type first checks if the other type is also a String, In your case it's a StringBuffer, so it returns false,
If you want to compare the contents, either use:

```
s1.equals(sb.toString())
```

or

```
s1.contentEquals(sb)
```